# Screen readers for arXiv/ar5iv?

Tags: arxiv, health

I am dyslexic and often struggle with reading and comprehension. Screen readers, such as VoiceOver on Macs, can be helpful in addressing these difficulties.

However, mathematics in arXiv papers can present a challenge for screen readers. A partial solution is ar5iv, which converts arXiv papers into HTML, improving accessibility (for example, see [this ar5iv paper](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2212.07286)).

However, I have yet to find a screen reader or configuration of a screen reader that will read ar5iv papers in a natural, fluid way. For example, VoiceOver says 'maths' after every MathML equation, interrupting the reading flow.

**Question:** Is there a screen reader or configuration that can effectively read arXiv or ar5iv papers, with mathematics included, in a more natural and seamless manner?

Comment: I think asking for screen readers for arXiv papers is asking the wrong question. What you want is a screen reader for LaTeX.

Comment: @Arno A screen reader for LaTeX would be sufficient - I agree. However, I think it is more likely that a screen reader exists which works well with the html (inc MathML) of ar5iv papers rather then the pdfs of arXiv papers.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but defenitely somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454944/is-there-screen-reader-software-or-a-built-in-method-that-supports-latex-equat

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am the creator and maintainer of ar5iv.

I think the idealized goal should be that the ar5iv HTML can be successfully used with all mainstream accessibility tools, including VoiceOver - which was mentioned in the original question. Maybe it is worth reporting the awkwardness of the verbosity of speaking "maths" to their team, with an example document attached?

Personally, I have successfully tested with two combinations of AT for proof-listening, one OS-specific and one cross-platform. But I have done this as a developer troubleshooting where to make the markup better, so I can not give you an unbiased assessment of reading quality.

If you have access to a Windows device, one could use NVDA with the MathCAT plug-in for mathematics, as described here:
https://addons.nvda-project.org/addons/MathCAT.en.html

On any device, you could use the recent versions of the read-aloud browser extension, which uses a different AT for math syntax called Speech rule engine (SRE). I have tried that with Chrome, read-aloud v2.5.0
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/read-aloud-a-text-to-spee/hdhinadidafjejdhmfkjgnolgimiaplp

Both seem to provide nominally acceptable readouts, but on a close listen we still have some artificial outcomes - sometimes due to not providing more in-depth markup, sometimes due to the tools not being sufficiently context-aware.

I welcome reports for such problems in ar5iv, when used with any accessible technology. An example of a VoiceOver report we still have to address can be seen here:
https://github.com/dginev/ar5iv/issues/95

Answer (score 0):

I have not-so-long math code in the papers I read, so I rely heavily on a tool called SwiftRead. Maybe it is helpful for you? However, the voice-over only works in the paid pro version.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use opendyslexic for reading if you haven't tried it already. I've found it useful when combined with arxiv-vanity (which i believe is just ar5iv) and have switched my fonts over to it. First time trying to read a paper from it I found the complexity of the prose appeared to drop from researcher level, to year 12 level (explaining why I'd always had trouble writing papers)

However, I do find it can mess up with maths sometimes though, but if you reduce the effort in reading the text around it there is more brainpower to process the maths or to flip to the original text and read the maths in its original form.